# Turning list into dict

Tags: python, python-3.4

my object looks like the following:

```
{
    "title": [
        "The UN chief calls on the Security Council to take action in halting Yemen's slide toward anarchy.",
        "Nabeel Rajab says Bahraini people are paying a heavy price for democratic and human rights values.",
        "Russia and Venezuela plan to hold joint military drills in the Caribbean Sea, a source says.",
        "Egypt\u2019s top prosecutor imposes a media gag order to block press coverage on recent killing of a female protester by police.",
        "Multinational companies are jockeying for position as nuclear talks between Iran and international negotiators shift to high gear amid hopes of a final deal.",
        "The UN refugee agency says EU maritime patrols in the Mediterranean are inadequate.",
        "The US and its allies are using Ukraine to isolate Russia in order to establish a so-called one world economic and political system, an analyst says.",
        "Sri Lanka\u2019s finance minister says the country will seek a bail-out of more than USD 4 billion from the IMF.",


    ],
    "link": [
        "/Detail/2015/02/12/397336/Yemen-collapsing-before-our-eyes",
        "/Detail/2015/02/12/397337/Bahrainis-pay-price-for-democracy",
        "/Detail/2015/02/12/397301/Russia-Venezuela-to-hold-joint-drills",
        "/Detail/2015/02/12/397334/Egypt-muffling-media-on-police-abuse",
        "/Detail/2015/02/12/397333/Multinational-companies-are-jockeying-for-position-as-nuclear-talks-between-Iran-and-international-negotiators-shift-to-high-gear-amid-hopes-of-a-final-deal",
        "/Detail/2015/02/12/397326/UN-maritime-patrols-insufficient-UN",
        "/Detail/2015/02/12/397328/US-using-Ukraine-to-isolate-Russia",
        "/Detail/2015/02/12/397318/Sri-Lanka-seeks-IMF-bailout",

    ],
    "date": [
        "Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:52PM",
        "Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:48PM",
        "Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:40PM",
        "Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:33PM",
        "Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:16PM",
        "Thu Feb 12, 2015 5:58PM",
        "Thu Feb 12, 2015 5:53PM",
        "Thu Feb 12, 2015 5:53PM",

    ]
}
```

**Question**
How do I get this list object into a nice dict where each object has 1 title, 1 link and 1 date?

I want to be able to run:

```
for item in items:
    print(item['link'], item['title'], item['date'] )
```

and receive 1 link, 1 title and 1 date as output on each print. I suspect zip() might be helpful but cannot figure it out.

Very thankful for any help

Comment: This is a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: From your usage, it seems you want a list of dictionaries, rather than a dictionary.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: it is a dictionary containing lists..

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's labelled turning a list to a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up elements from the three lists:

```
for link, title, date in zip(items['link'], items['title'], items['date']):
```

There is no need to turn anything into a dictionary here.

Demo:

```
>>> for link, title, date in zip(items['link'], items['title'], items['date']):
...     print(link)
...     print(title)
...     print(date)
...     print('------')
... 
/Detail/2015/02/12/397336/Yemen-collapsing-before-our-eyes
The UN chief calls on the Security Council to take action in halting Yemen's slide toward anarchy.
Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:52PM
------
/Detail/2015/02/12/397337/Bahrainis-pay-price-for-democracy
Nabeel Rajab says Bahraini people are paying a heavy price for democratic and human rights values.
Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:48PM
------
# etc.
```

You can rebuild a dictionary for each loop iteration too:

```
for values in zip(*items.values()):
    item = dict(zip(items.keys(), values))
    print(item)
```

This relies on the fact that `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` produce their results in matching order.

Demo:

```
>>> for values in zip(*items.values()):
...     item = dict(zip(items.keys(), values))
...     print(item)
... 
{'date': 'Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:52PM', 'link': '/Detail/2015/02/12/397336/Yemen-collapsing-before-our-eyes', 'title': "The UN chief calls on the Security Council to take action in halting Yemen's slide toward anarchy."}
{'date': 'Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:48PM', 'link': '/Detail/2015/02/12/397337/Bahrainis-pay-price-for-democracy', 'title': 'Nabeel Rajab says Bahraini people are paying a heavy price for democratic and human rights values.'}
{'date': 'Thu Feb 12, 2015 6:40PM', 'link': '/Detail/2015/02/12/397301/Russia-Venezuela-to-hold-joint-drills', 'title': 'Russia and Venezuela plan to hold joint military drills in the Caribbean Sea, a source says.'}
# etc.
```

Comment: Thanks Martjin, hmm whatif I know want to save each object into the database and before saving each object I need to chack that the object which is going to save is unique and that the database do not contain its link already?

Comment: if session.query(Presstv).filter_by(link=items['link']).first() == None:
            try:
                session.add(news)


.... Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: The link is now referenced by `link`, not `items['link']`.

Comment: @Toothfairy: I gave you an alternative option where you can use `item['link']` too. Note the name, `item` *singular*.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go with Martijn Pieters' solution, but if you insist on your usage, you could do:

```
items = []
for i in range(len(myDict["title"])):
    items.append({"title":myDict["title"][i], "link":myDict["link"][i], "date":myDict["date"][i]})
```

Comment: Yes, my idea's the same except with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
items = [{"title" : items["title"][i],
          "link" : items["link"][i],
          "date" : items["date"][i]}

         for i in range(len(items["title"]))]


import pprint
pprint.pprint(items)
```